# How can I insert the data mentioned in the insert query below, separately for different users using PHP

Tags: php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM guests WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index2.php');
    //header('location: justfortest.php');

} else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
}

if (!empty($_POST['brief']) && !empty($_POST['measure']) && !empty($_POST['status']) && is_array($_POST['brief']) && is_array($_POST['measure']) && is_array($_POST['status']) && count($_POST['brief']) === count($_POST['measure'])) {
    $brief_array = $_POST['brief'];
    $measure_array = $_POST['measure'];
    $status_array = $_POST['status'];
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($brief_array);$i++) {
        $brief = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $brief_array[$i]);
        $msure = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $measure_array[$i]);
        $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $status_array[$i]);
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO goals (brief_about, measure, progress) VALUES ('$brief', '$msure', '$status')");
    }
}
```

Here are the codes for a user login and inserting the data needed for different users separately.

Any hep would be appreciated.

Comment: To me it is quite unclear what you're asking. Could you start your question with an explanation of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Actually I want to insert the data shown in the insert query, separately for different users on there login

Comment: You could add an `userId` or `username` column to your `goals` table so you can identify which goals belong to which user.

Comment: I have tried adding both the columns. But as I am new to PHP, so I am not able to understand where I need to add the logic to insert username and store separate data for different users.

Comment: Actually I  want to store the data in the database for separate users, so each user can access his data after login

Comment: I can understand it is confusing in the beginning. Perhaps it would be better to read a good tutorial on this topic? Not the basic online stuff. You're making obvious beginners mistakes like inserting PHP variables into your query, escaping them is just not good enough. Use prepared statements. When you've mastered the examples in the tutorial, adding a user column to your goals table will be easy. So easy that I cannot understand what the problem could be: You've got three colums in there already, why would be hard to add a fourth?

Comment: Yes you are right sir. Actually adding a fourth is not hard and also I did insert the 4th column values as well. Its that I want to insert data according to login sessions for different users. That is the part I am stuck at. So if you could just help me with the logic or you could just guide me with a good tutorial that would be helpful here. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've inserted the username in your query. The username is retrieved from the `$_SESSION` and it must be set when a valid user logs in, and unset when an error occurs or when the user logs out.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM guests WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    // removed the weird success thing here
    header('location: index2.php');
} else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    // always unset the username in session on errors and logout
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && // session username must be set
    !empty($_POST['brief']) && 
    !empty($_POST['measure']) && 
    !empty($_POST['status']) && 
    is_array($_POST['brief']) && 
    is_array($_POST['measure']) && 
    is_array($_POST['status']) && 
    count($_POST['brief']) === count($_POST['measure'])) {
    $brief_array   = $_POST['brief'];
    $measure_array = $_POST['measure'];
    $status_array  = $_POST['status'];
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($brief_array);$i++) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['username']);
        $brief    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $brief_array[$i]);
        $msure    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $measure_array[$i]);
        $status   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $status_array[$i]);
        $query    =  "INSERT INTO goals (username, brief_about, measure, progress) 
                      VALUES ('$username', '$brief', '$msure', '$status')"
        mysqli_query($con,$query);
    }
}
```

You will have to add the column `username` to the table `goals`. After this you can query your database like this:

`SELECT * FROM goals WHERE username = ?`

where the '?' stands for `$_SESSION['username']`.

I haven't added prepared statements, because that's not what this question is about.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it sir.